# Problems getting an R-function with linear model included to run

Tags: r, function

I'd like to create a function in R that I can apply to biological data for size correction.
My data look like this:

[Snapshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85idV.png)

structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 12L, 23L, 34L, 45L, 56L,
66L, 67L, 68L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L), .Label = c("rat1",
"rat10", "rat11", "rat12", "rat13", "rat14", "rat15", "rat16",
"rat17", "rat18", "rat19", "rat2", "rat20", "rat21", "rat22",
"rat23", "rat24", "rat25", "rat26", "rat27", "rat28", "rat29",
"rat3", "rat30", "rat31", "rat32", "rat33", "rat34", "rat35",
"rat36", "rat37", "rat38", "rat39", "rat4", "rat40", "rat41",
"rat42", "rat43", "rat44", "rat45", "rat46", "rat47", "rat48",
"rat49", "rat5", "rat50", "rat51", "rat52", "rat53", "rat54",
"rat55", "rat56", "rat57", "rat58", "rat59", "rat6", "rat60",
"rat61", "rat62", "rat63", "rat64", "rat65", "rat66", "rat67",
"rat68", "rat7", "rat8", "rat9"), class = "factor"), population = structure(c(1L,
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), size = c(39.72,
46.72, 38.37, 40.8, 46.57, 35.93, 51.69, 40.97, 45.39, 43.67,
43.68, 39.2, 45.07, 42.11, 46.91, 45.99, 42.43, 41.36, 42.54,
38.41), trait = c(3.657, 4.096, 3.186, 4.286, 3.901, 2.882, 4.666,
4.635, 4.93, 4.264, 4.329, 3.493, 5.142, 4.859, 4.272, 3.5, 4.199,
4.434, 4.278, 3.211)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

And here the function:

```
    sizecorr=function(input_data,input_trait){
        x = input_data 
        xnew = x 
        xnew$size = mean(x$size)
        z = lm(input_trait ~ size + population, data = x, na.action = na.exclude)
        res = residuals(z)
        yhat = predict(z,xnew)
        m = (res+yhat)
        }
```

However, when I now run this function on my data like this

```
sizecorr(d,"trait")
```

I always get this error:

Error in model.frame.default(formula = input_trait ~ size + population,  :
variable lengths differ (found for 'size')

The data are all clean (no missing data) and in the right format. Can someone pinpoint the problem?

Comment: 1) `x = d` should be `x = input_data`, right?; 2) Do `length(input_trait)` and `nrow(input_data)` return the same value?

Comment: Can you share part of your data? Type dput(head(d, 20)) and post the output inside your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing string input to the function. Use `as.formula` or `reformula` to construct the formula. Also do you really need so many copies of data? (`input_data`, `x`, `xnew`).

```
sizecorr=function(input_data,input_trait){
  x = input_data 
  xnew = x
  xnew$size = mean(x$size)
  z = lm(reformulate(c('size', 'population'), input_trait), 
         data = x, na.action = na.exclude)
  res = residuals(z)
  yhat = predict(z,xnew)
  m = (res+yhat)
  m
}
sizecorr(d,"trait")
```

Comment: Oh indeed, it now works! – What I'm wondering though is why  my old function still did not work if I do not pass a string, but an object, to the function. In other words, why does my old function not work if I use trait without the ""?

Comment: If you use `trait` without "" it is not an object. Try to put `trait` in the console and see what you get.

Comment: Ok, got it! So it seems then there is no easier way than using 'trait' as string and reformulate the model? – thanks a lot

Comment: Ok, will accept your answer in a second. One more question: if I now want to bind the function's output "m" directly onto the "input_data" as a column with a new name, why can't I simply add these two lines at the end of the function sizeCorr.header<-paste0(input_trait,".sizeCorr") and input_data$sizeCorr.header<-m

Comment: You cannot use string variable with `$` to add new column. You can do `input[sizeCorr.header] <- m`